# Create Set of objects from mongoose.find()

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I need to create an object of filters based on unique values in my data to pass to my front-end application. I need one of the filters to be an array of objects. My previous method of `[...new Set()]` isn't working, I'm getting an error that says `name: is unexpected, expected }`

My other `[...new Set()]` functions all work as expected.

```
    let allEmployees = await db.Employee.find();

    let filters = {
      hiringManager: [...new Set(allEmployees.map(emp => {
         emplid: emp.emplid,
         name: emp.name,
         hrOrg: emp.hrOrg}
       ))].sort(function(a, b){return a.name - b.name}),
      countries:[...new Set(allEmployees.map(emp => emp.country))].sort(),
      globalGrades: [...new Set(allEmployees.map(emp => emp.globalGrade))].sort(),
      jobFamilies: [...new Set(allEmployees.map(emp => emp.jobFamily))].sort()
    };
```

Any ideas on how to return a Set of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would say to avoid using spread operator with Set. Because I got some interpretation issue sometimes in specific systems (spread operator was not good dealing with array-like).

```js
const allEmployees = [{
  country: 'France',
}, {
  country: 'Westeros',
}, {
  country: 'France',
}];

const unique = Array.from(new Set(allEmployees.map(emp => emp.country))).sort();

console.log(unique);
```

---

Then in your case you miss a parenthesis. If you use `map(emp => {` like this, `map` will consider what is inside the `{` a function definition. If you want to return data directly from map, wrap it inside of `()` like :

```
map(() => ({

}));
```

```js
const allEmployees = [{
  country: 'France',
}, {
  country: 'Westeros',
}, {
  country: 'France',
}];


const ret = [
  ...new Set(allEmployees.map(emp => ({
    emplid: emp.country,
  }))),
];

console.log(ret);
```